# Minko Engine SDK - Tons of compile errors

Tags: minko

I just pulled Minko Engine from github and followed all the instructions. Some of the projects have a ton of compile errors. I'm compiling this on Windows 10 with VS2015.

Here are some of the errors

Error   LNK2005 "bool __cdecl std::uncaught_exception(void)" (?uncaught_exception@std@@YA_NXZ) already defined in libcpmt.lib(uncaught.obj) minko-test  E:\OneDrive\Projects\Minko\minko\test\msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) 1   Build
Error   LNK2005 "protected: __cdecl std::basic_ios >::basic_ios >(void)" (??0?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IEAA@XZ) already defined in libcpmt.lib(cin.obj)    minko-test  E:\OneDrive\Projects\Minko\minko\test\msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) 1   Build
Error   LNK2005 "protected: __cdecl std::basic_streambuf >::basic_streambuf >(void)" (??0?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IEAA@XZ) already defined in FlyweightTest.obj minko-test  E:\OneDrive\Projects\Minko\minko\test\msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) 1   Build
Error   LNK2005 "public: char __cdecl std::basic_ios >::widen(char)const " (?widen@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEBADD@Z) already defined in libcpmt.lib(cin.obj)    minko-test  E:\OneDrive\Projects\Minko\minko\test\msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) 1   Build
Error   LNK2005 "public: class std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl std::basic_ostream >::flush(void)" (?flush@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAAEAV12@XZ) already defined in main.obj  minko-test  E:\OneDrive\Projects\Minko\minko\test\msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) 1   Build
Error   LNK2005 "public: class std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl std::basic_ostream >::operator<<(double)" (??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAAEAV01@N@Z) already defined in EffectParserTest.obj  minko-test  E:\OneDrive\Projects\Minko\minko\test\msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) 1   Build
Error   LNK2005 "public: class std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl std::basic_ostream >::operator<<(float)" (??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAAEAV01@M@Z) already defined in AmbientLightTest.obj   minko-test  E:\OneDrive\Projects\Minko\minko\test\msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) 1   Build
Error   LNK2005 "public: class std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl std::basic_ostream >::operator<<(int)" (??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAAEAV01@H@Z) already defined in FlyweightTest.obj    minko-test  E:\OneDrive\Projects\Minko\minko\test\msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) 1   Build
Error   LNK2005 "public: class std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl std::basic_ostream >::operator<<(unsigned int)" (??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAAEAV01@I@Z) already defined in SignalTest.obj  minko-test  E:\OneDrive\Projects\Minko\minko\test\msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) 1   Build
Error   LNK2005 "public: class std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl std::basic_ostream >::operator<<(unsigned __int64)" (??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAAEAV01@_K@Z) already defined in FlyweightTest.obj  minko-test  E:\OneDrive\Projects\Minko\minko\test\msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) 1   Build
Error   LNK2005 "public: class std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl std::basic_ostream >::operator<<(void const *)" (??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAAEAV01@PEBX@Z) already defined in FlyweightTest.obj    minko-test  E:\OneDrive\Projects\Minko\minko\test\msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) 1   Build
Error   LNK2005 "public: class std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl std::basic_ostream >::put(char)" (?put@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAAEAV12@D@Z) already defined in EffectParserTest.obj minko-test  E:\OneDrive\Projects\Minko\minko\test\msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) 1   Build
Error   LNK2005 "public: class std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl std::basic_ostream >::write(char const *,__int64)" (?write@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAAEAV12@PEBD_J@Z) already defined in minko-plugin-serializer.lib(TypeSerializer.obj) minko-test  E:\OneDrive\Projects\Minko\minko\test\msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) 1   Build

Comment: 'dev' or 'master' branch? IMHO you might want to post this on the issue tracker (https://github.com/aerys/minko/issues) instead since this is not a question per-say.

Comment: This is the master branch

Comment: Please try the "dev" branch. Also please format your post to use code tags.